# writing source and custom sink using flume-ng

Tags: flume

I am new to flume-NG. I want my source to send some unique xml files to the channel one by one. The channel will validate the xml files and send the validity(either true or false) and the xml file to th custom sink. This sink will write the valid files and invalid files to different directories in HDFS. I am not sure which source to use. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

None of the current ones will fit your use case. The `SpoolingDirectorySource` is line-oriented so XML files will confuse it and not arrive in one piece.

I suggest you write a custom source for your application.

Comment: Shall i start writing my logic in the process method of my custom source? What does the channel accepts from the source? Is it an event or any file?

Comment: No. Have a look at `SpoolDirectorySource` for an example. `SpoolDirectoryRunnable.run` is pretty close to what you want. The channel accepts events from the source. Note, that you can and should send batches where possible for performance reasons.